# Replace paramType in SpringFox

Tags: springfox, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have this `@ApiImplicitParam` annotation used by SpringFox to document endpoint. I want to migrate to `springdoc`.

```
  @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Proxy", value = "Authorization value", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")
  public .. endpoint(...){
     .....
  }
```

I replaced it to this:

```
  @Parameter(name = "Proxy", description = "Authorization value", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "header")
  public .. endpoint(...){
     .....
  }
```

But I get `Cannot resolve method 'dataType'` and `Cannot resolve method 'paramType'`. Do you know what should be the proper replacement for these values in `springdoc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, `dataType` isn't supported. Instead we have `content`, `schema`, and `array` (for array elements) fields. It can be used in either of the below ways

- Using just `schema`

  ```java
  @Parameter(name = "Proxy", description = "Authorization Value", required = true, in = ParameterIn.HEADER, schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class))
  ```
- Using `schema` in conjunction with `content`

  ```java
  @Parameter(name = "Proxy", description = "Authorization Value", required = true, in = ParameterIn.HEADER, content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = String.class)))
  ```

I've not tried the first one personally and in fact is the first time I saw it. (Maybe it was introduced in Springdoc 2.x?) But it seems to be cleaner way compared to the second.